# Android- File downloading from server but saving with different file name and extension

Tags: android, download, server

I have made an Android app that downloads a file from a server and saves it to a directory in the internal storage. First the code validates if the link exists and if the link exists, it downloads the file. The file is downloading but when I go Folder and see if file exists, a file exists but that is not the file I had placed on the server. Everything works inside an AsyncTask

Here goes my code:

```
String fileName = "abc.pdf";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100%
            // progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);

            // Output stream
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/MyApp/");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Use : https://github.com/smanikandan14/ThinDownloadManager

Comment: `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/MyApp/");`. When /MyApp/ is a folder then you have no file name at all. You can put any file name you want of course:  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + "/MyApp/myfilename.jpg");

Answer (score 1):

once I am also suffering this problem and at end I making one Generic AsyncTask Class which is just Download file from server and stored in Local folder.In this code Snippet I am always getting mp3 file From server so I am statically set .mp3 format.you can change this code According to your requirement.

```
   @Override
protected File doInBackground(Void... params) {


    //File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music";

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + ConstansClass.FOLDERNAME);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }


    String filename = "YOUR LOCAL STORAGE FILE NAME TITLE";
    yourDir = new File(file, filename + ".mp3");
    if (yourDir.exists()) {
        return yourDir;
    }


    String url = "YOUR FILE DOWNLOADING URL";

    URL u = null;
    try {
        DebugLog.e("Request Url" + url);
        u = new URL(url);
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(yourDir));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        DebugLog.d("Download Complete in On Background");


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        sucess = false;
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        sucess = false;
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        sucess = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
        DebugLog.e("Error ::" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return yourDir;
}
```

**Parameter**

- **filename** : your file name which is stored in your local folder
- **url** : Your Server Link where you can download file.

**Note**

- Please Make Sure your Downloading File URL is Perfect.
- You Must need Read Write and Internet Permission in Manifest.

I hope you are Clear with my Idea.
Thanks,

**Best of Luck**

Comment: Even this doesn't work. Now there's no file in the folder.